# Horizontal lines start to appear in monitor after 1 hour of usage

Tags: display

I am using 15 inchn CRT monitor
its been working fine until these days
Now, I get to see Horizontal lines start in the monitor after 1 hour of computer usage
Also the screen bottom 1/10 portion is blackened
Is this is a sign of ageing monitor or anything else

Answer (score 0):

This can be a sign of the monitor being on its way out. Might need replacing soon. That said it's worth testing with another VGA cable, and perhaps another graphics card, as either of those could be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a hardware problem, but which piece of hardware? I've seen CRTs do this in the past, and 15 inches sounds old. Do you have access to a different monitor you could try for an hour to see if it helps? Does shutting it off for a few seconds and then turning it back on make a difference? It could also be the graphics card, but it's hard to tell from here.